# Deleting a 'friend' that added you using self-referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can implement reverse relationships, so if UserA adds UserB, then it shows UserA in B's profile, and visa versa.
But I cannot figure out how to let UserB remove UserA as a friend, if UserA added UserB.
I've tried so many different ways, but everytime I change something it moves the problem elsewhere! I can't tell if the fundamental issue is:

- a. how the FriendshipsController destroy method is defined
- b. whether I need another controller specifically just to handle
  InverseFriendships destroy
- c. if I need to customize the routes
- d. if all the above are ok, but the code I have in my views (specifically
  the _suggested_connections partial) is calling the wrong controller
  and/or route
- e. or none of the above.

Code snippets below:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

      def destroy
        @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
        @friendship.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
        redirect_to current_user
      end
```

In the view

```
        <% @user.inverse_friends.each do |inverse_friendship| %>
      <li>
        <%= inverse_friendship.name %>
        <%= link_to "remove", @user.inverse_friendships, :method => :delete, :class => "btn-small btn-danger" %><br />
        <%= image_tag inverse_friendship.avatar(:thumb) %>
```

My models:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
  attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id
end 

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :friends, through: :friendships
    has_many :inverse_friendships, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user
```

And routes:

```
    resources :friendships

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
  resources :users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is a:

> a. how the FriendshipsController destroy method is defined

You're looking for the `friendship` in the `current_user.friendships`, but it's not there.  It's in `inverse_friendships`.

You'd need to either check both associations, or let the controller know which one you're looking for.  The latter is probably preferable since although they are the same class, they *are* different resources.  Something like this maybe:

```
# In routes, route inverse friendships to the same controller, but with a
# different path (I'm routing everything here, you may not need that.)
resources :friendships
resources :inverse_friendships, :controller => 'friendships'


# Then in your friendships controller, use the path to determine which 
# collection you're working with:
#
def destroy
  @friendship = collection.find(params[:id])
  # ...
end

# the other collection methods would use the same collection, if you needed them,
# for example:
def create
  @friendship = collection.build(params[:friendship])
  # ..
end

protected

# simple case statement here, but you get the idea
def collection
  case request.path
  when /\/inverse_friendships/ then current_user.inverse_friendships
  else current_user.friendships
  end
end
```

Finally in your view you'd route to an inverse friendship like:

```
<%= link_to "remove", inverse_friendship_path(friendship), :method => :delete %>
```

A normal friendship could use the shorter form, or the full named route:

```
<%= link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete %>
OR
<%= link_to "remove", friendship_path(friendship), :method => :delete %>
```

---

**EDIT:** Searching both associations.

Of course if you wanted to keep it simple, and had no other use for `inverse_friends` being a separate resource, you could always just...

```
def destroy
  id, cid = params[:id], current_user.id

  # search both associations (two queries)
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by_id(id) ||
                  current_user.inverse_friendships.find(id)

  # or query friendship looking for both types
  @friendship = Friendship.
                  where("user_id = ? OR friend_id = ?", cid, cid).find(id)

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks numbers1311407, that seems to make sense.  I will try it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: I still couldn't get it work after following your advise.  In the end I created a separate controller for inverse_friendships and that did the trick.

Comment: Ok, slightly embarrassed here.  You're right, it does work, although I needed to adjust the code in the view slightly.  Anyway, cheers for the help.